# Finite Field Arithmetic _ Montgomery reduction

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-field, montgomery-multiplication, arithmetic

In an attempt to understand the mathematical operations related to encryption with elliptic curves, in particular finite field arithmetic (Modular reduction) I found in the Montgomery reduction that Montgomery form is an alternative finite field representation. what is this suppose to mean ? what it does differ from the usual finite field representation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When the $r = 2^k$ this is usually performed by shift operations. This is a trick of the Montgomery. The trial division is transferred into shifts.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84327/18298). Actually, the title of the paper is quite clear about this; Modular multiplication without trial division ,1985

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Montgomery reduction work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/84327/how-does-montgomery-reduction-work)

Answer (score 0):

Montgomery arithmetic is a technique for modular computation modulo some integer $m$. It centers on Montgomery reduction, an alternative to reduction modulo $m$ by [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division).

Montgomery reduction uses an alternate representation of the [ring of integers modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) $m$. That is, the representation of a ring element $A$ as digits is not the same as in the [Positional Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation), where $A$ is represented by digits $a_j$ in some base $\beta$, with $0\le a_j<\beta$ and $A=\sum a_j\,\beta^j$ (and perhaps $A<m$, making the tuple unique). In Montgomery representation with $m<\beta^\ell$ and $\gcd(m,\beta)=1$, a ring element $A$ is represented by a tuple of $\ell$ digits $a_j$, with $0\le a_j<\beta$ and $\beta^\ell\,A\;\equiv\;\sum a_j\,\beta^j\pmod m$ (and perhaps $\sum a_j\,\beta^j<m$, making the tuple unique).

Montgomery reduction avoids the issue that in [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) in PSN, the step of estimating the next digit in the quotient is difficult and occasionally off-by-one, thus requiring a correction before (or at) the processing of the next quotient digit. In the bulk of Montgomery reduction this is replaced by a simple operation with no exceptional case. That simplicity makes it easier to interleave modular multiplication and reduction, which in turn reduces memory accesses.

---

Montgomery reduction has little relation with Montgomery elliptic curves. The closest is that for Montgomery elliptic curves on a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of large characteristic (that is field $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ with large $p$), arithmetic modulo $p$ can use Montgomery reduction.